# Can we use Node.js cluster using single core processor?

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js application which receives multiple requests concurrently from clients. If this application is running on a server with a multi-core processor, we can reap the advantages of Node.js cluster to scale-up the application by creating multiple workers which can actually be executed in parallel on a muti-core processor to manage the load.

With Node.js being single-threaded and if my application is running on a server having a single CPU, can we use cluster to scale-up the application?

Answer (score 1):

Intel cores usually have hyper-threading, allowing two threads per core at (slightly?) slower performance. Even with a single core, you should be able to reap those benefits.